# How to make my app to show listing screenshots without it being tapped

Tags: google-play

This is not related to programming, but related to play store listing. So I want my app to show the listing screenshots even when it is not opened on the Play Store. e.g., when I search for Instagram, I see something like this:

[image]

But when I search for my app, it only shows me the name and some other details of the app, but no other data like ratings, screenshots, etc. Is there any way to make it so that my app also appears like that. Currently my app appears like follows:

[image]